# CMD nslookup script returns "timed-out" error

Tags: cmd.exe, script, nslookup

I wanted to write a CMD script to automatically check the MX records for a set of domains (stored in a TXT file) for reporting purpose.

When I do the `nslookup` for a single domain, there is no problem:

[image: nslookup]

When i use my script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "inputFile=domains.txt"
set "outputFile=mx_results.txt"

echo. > %outputFile%

for /f "delims=" %%i in (%inputFile%) do (
   for /f "delims=" %%j in ('nslookup -q=mx %%i') do (
      set "result=%%j"
   )

   echo !result! >> %outputFile%
```

I get an error message: `*** Request to UnKnown timed-out`

[image: script nslookup]

The domains.txt file contains the following three test domains:

```
gmail.com
apple.com
microsoft.com
```

Is there something wrong with the script, or what is the problem?

**Edit 1:**
*I followed the advice and created a new answer.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is there something wrong with the script?

There are a couple of errors:

1. Your parentheses don't match up (there is a missing `)`.
2. `echo !result! >> %outputFile%` is in the wrong place (it should be after the previous `echo` otherwise you only get the last line of output in the `for` loop).
3. You need to escape the `=` in `q=mx` using `^`.
4. `findstr` produces some output you probably don't want (for example `Non-authoritative answer:`.

Try the following script:

```
@echo off
rem avoid polluting global envoronment space
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "inputFile=domains.txt"
set "outputFile=mx_results.txt"

echo. > %outputFile%

for /f "delims=" %%i in (%inputFile%) do (
   for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%j in ('nslookup -q^=mx %%i 2^>nul ^| find "MX"') do (
   set "result=%%j"
   echo !result! >> %outputFile%
   )
)   

rem type %outputFile%

endlocal
```

Output:

```
gmail.com       MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
gmail.com       MX preference = 5, mail exchanger = gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
gmail.com       MX preference = 20, mail exchanger = alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
gmail.com       MX preference = 40, mail exchanger = alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
apple.com       MX preference = 20, mail exchanger = mx-in-mdn.apple.com
apple.com       MX preference = 20, mail exchanger = mx-in-rno.apple.com
apple.com       MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = mx-in.g.apple.com
```

Note:

I used `findstr` and error redirection to remove unwanted output from `nslookup`

Comment: Thanks for spotting the errors and for cleaning up the output (this would have been my next question). While I was looking for a way to clean the output, I found the command "dig +short mx". It needed BIND 9 to work, but I guess I found a solution for more or less my whole scenario (see above edit 1).
One question, what do you mean with "rem avoid polluting global envoronment space"?

Comment: `setlocal` stops variables being leaked into the calling `cmd` shell.

Comment: Note: Changing your question after you've received answers is inappropriate, as it invalidates the answers you've received. It can even make those answers wrong, and adversely affect the reputation of those who answered. If you now have a new or additional question, create a new post and ask it there; you can link back to this one if needed for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention, I just need one line of the output and not the whole MX data set. It also does not matter which data set is stored. Furthermore, if there is a typo in one of the domains, the output should store an error message.
My solution for the moment, in combination with BIND 9, looks like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "inputFile=domains.txt"
set "outputFile=mx_results.txt"

echo. > %outputFile%

for /f "delims=" %%i in (%inputFile%) do (
   set "result=ERROR"
   for /f "delims=" %%j in ('dig +short mx %%i') do (
      set "result=%%j"
   )

   echo !result! >> %outputFile%
)
```